# Mainstream vs Extended Support phase

Tags: windows

What's the difference between Microsoft's `Mainstream Support phase` and `Extended Support phase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read [Microsoft's Support policy here](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/lifepolicy).

[image]

Comment: Since the MS footnote is poor, I'd add that hotfixes are generally only provided as workarounds for critical bugs prior to a patch being released, or for privately reported unusual cases.  99% of the time they're not something average users should have to worry about.

Comment: So in _Extended Support phase_ non-security updates are paid